# Can strcmp() Compare a Dynamic Character Array with a Static Character array?

Tags: c++, arrays

Perhaps this is a stupid question, but the reason I ask is because I'm using `strcmp()` to compare a dynamic array with a static array and it's seemingly giving the wrong result. The arrays should be equal, but `strcmp()` is returning false. When I pause my program, the only two things that differ between those arrays are their memory locations.

I can't show you the whole code, but here's part of my function which has these two variables in it:

```
stock * Table::retrieveStock(const char tick[])
{
    uint8_t index = hashing(tick);
    if (table[index])
    {
        bool test = strcmp(table[index]->data->getTick(), tick);
    //irrelevant code
```

and here's how some of the pointers are declared in the `Table` class:

```
struct node
    {
        stock * data;
        node * next;
        node()
        {
            stock();
            next = nullptr;
        }
        node(stock *& item)
        {
            data = item;
            next = nullptr;
        }
    };
    node ** table;
```

I have an array of class objects in it, anyways, the point is that I'm comparing two tick values, which should be equal. One I'm pulling out of the object with the `getTick()` function:

```
const char * stock::getTick() const
{
    return tick;
}
```

and one is passed into the function: `const char tick[]`. I'm quite clueless as to what is wrong with my code here. I would love to give you guys more code to work with, but I can't see how it would do anything but make solving this issue more difficult for you.

Edit: Maybe this will help; I just thought of it. This is exactly what my compiler says the values are:

```
curr->data  0x005d93e8 {tick=0x005d9f38 "TSLA" name=0x005da100 "2" value=2.00000000 ...}    stock *
```

and

```
tick    0x004afb20 "TSLA"   const char *
```

Comment: Your question is for C++ not for C , please change tag.

Comment: @BobRun I tagged this as C to stop people from telling me to use the string class. I've changed that, but how did you know that was C++ and not C?

Comment: Are both null-terminated strings? `strcmp` depends on null-terminated.

Comment: Don't forget `strcmp` returns `0` for a match. It doesn't return `true` or `false`.

Comment: @JonathanPotter What does it return if the strings don't match?

Comment: A positive or negative number depending on the relative order of the two strings.

Comment: Put more clearly your variable `test` will be false if the two strings compare equal.

Comment: @DanielJour I think I put it perfectly clearly, thank you :)

Comment: @JonathanPotter Well, the fact that I though `strcmp()` returns a true or false value was the source of my error. If you want to post that as an answer I'd be happy to mark it as the correct answer. Just make sure you specify in your answer that setting a bool to 0 makes it false.

Comment: @LarryK  maybe Table::retrieveStock(const char tick[])

Comment: @LarryK: `->getTick()` and `nullptr` can only be C++ and not C. Of course, the question is why you would not want to use `std::string`. On Stackoverflow, 99% of all beginners who do not use it either are not allowed to because it's homework or because they believe in urban legends about some performance loss or because they've read it in some ancient book or tutorial from the 90s.

Comment: @LarryK (Actually, with some imagination, both `->getTick()` and `nullptr` could be C, but it's unlikely).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strcmp()` returns 0 for a match (and non-zero for no match). It doesn't return `true` or `false` as you are expecting.

Comment: Thank you. I feel like such an idiot for not realizing that. I even looked up the `strcmp()` function, saw that it returned an integer and not a bool, and thought nothing of that. I hope the internet points I give you suffice as sufficient compensation for my wasting your time.